# Flexible Unity Event Declaration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

I have a time value between 0 and 1. And I want users to specify any value (or multiple values) to add events on inpector.

So user can add events for 0.1f, 0.54f, 0.99f... etc. Those elements will be part of list. Maybe declared Unity Events in an array of classes.

But I don't want to put Unity Event for each element. Because those GameObjects will be a lot in the scene. With multiple Unity Events and hundreds of objects will add up. So users can decide if they want to use those Unity Events (declare actually) or not. User can have 5 points but can use none or 3 or 5 events with them.

Any ideas? Or declared but not used (null) Unity Events cost anything in builds other than eating inspector space on editor?

Comment: Id guess some form of 1 event for on change of value and then a dictionary of events and values to occur at. Did you try anything?

Comment: Users will add their custom events on inspector and they'll determine the event count. Or they don't use at all. I'm trying to find best solution for it by trying to avoid unnecessary Unity Event declerations.

Comment: I don’t think you grasped my suggestion. As the float for value would be one. The method the other and as the value changes the methods against the value can be called either noting that any skipped through if desired behavior (eg it was .6 now .75 an event was listed for .7 could be run and then the 0.75 if listed etc) which gives you 1 event with multiple outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Since this may be a long explanation I'll put it as an answer.  You could possibly create a single `UnityEvent<float>` which will be called for the specified time and use the time as a "parameter" to the event.
For example...

```
[Serializeable]
public struct EventTiming
{
    public float triggerTime;
    public bool  triggerEvent;
}

public class Poo
{
    [Serializefield]
    public EventTiming[] eventTimings;
    public UnityEvent<float> event;

    int timingIdx = 0;

    ... then somewhere you can use it like this...

    foreach (EventTiming timing in eventTimings)
    {
        if (timing.triggerEvent)
            event?.Invoke(timing.triggerTime);
    }

    ... or ...
    
    if (Time.deltaTime >= eventTimings[timingIdx].triggerTime)
    {
       if (eventTimings[timingIdx].triggerEvent)
           event?.Invoke(eventTimings[timingIdx]);
       timingIdx++;
    }
}
```

or something.

Comment: Sorry, what is the purpose of <float> here? This looks like it is for same event but for different times. But I want them to use different events for different times. https://i.imgur.com/xxxtL5h.png So I can avoid unused Event declarations. If user won't use those, i don't want to declare them somehow. Also I'm asking if is it bad to left null like this when they're hundreds of them.